# Python login form with requests on aspx

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am new to Python. So please dont be angry if my question is too noob and my english is bad T.T I want to scrape data from the admin page of our company CMS which based on ASP. I read a lot of tut on Internet about BeautifulSoup and Request Module. But is doens't work for me. Could you guy give me some help/hints? Thanks in advance.

The login url is:

> http://thuvientulap.org/login.aspx

and my code:

```
#import libraries
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL="http://thuvientulap.org/login.aspx"

username="user"
password="password"

s=requests.Session()
r=s.get(URL)

soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content,'html.parser')

VIEWSTATE=soup.find(id="__VIEWSTATE")['value']
EVENTVALIDATION=soup.find(id="__EVENTVALIDATION")['value']
VIEWSTATEGENERATOR=soup.find(id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR")['value']

login_data={"__VIEWSTATE":VIEWSTATE,
"txt_name_login":username,
"txt_password_ogin":password,
"__VIEWSTATE":VIEWSTATE,
"__EVENTVALIDATION":EVENTVALIDATION,
"__VIEWSTATEGENERATORT":VIEWSTATEGENERATOR,
}

r = s.post(URL, data=login_data)

admin_url =("http://thuvientulap.org/admin.aspx")
r = s.get(admin_url)

print (r.url)
print (r.text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing any headers:

```
import requests
s=requests.Session()
url ="http://thuvientulap.org/login.aspx"
r=s.get(url)
dct=s.cookies.get_dict()#you will get a ASP.net cookie pass it in header 
                         along with other headers


aid=dct["ASP.NET_SessionId"]
head = {ASP.NET_SessionId=aid,.....}
r = s.post(url, data=login_data,headers=head)
```

To get info about which specific headers you have to pass and all the parameters required for POST

- Open link in google chrome.
- Open Developers Console(fn + F12).
- There search for login doc (if cannot find, input wrong details and submit).
- You will get info about request headers and POST parameters.

Comment: Sorry for being so noob. I dont understand your answer. But i found the problem. I just added into array login data "BtnLogin":"". Now it works like a charm. But if you can help me with a more detail answer, i will be very happy. I am so sorry for asking too much.

Comment: ohh...no problem In my answer I suggested you to pass a parameter called `Header` as all POST and GET method have headers it's good to pass headers as sometimes it may contain important information such as cookie values